# How to make an AppleScript app open another one?

Tags: macos, applescript

The title says it all. What would be the line of code to open a specific app created in AppleScript?

```
tell application "userappname" to open/launch/what?
```

What would be the last piece of the code? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have application XYZ.app and you want to open that from AppleScript, this would be the code:

```
tell application "XYZ"
    activate
end tell
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be in /Applications nor do you need to include the _path_ as long as it has been indexed by Spotlight it should find it.

Comment: I just tested your theory and yes you are correct.  The file does not need to be located in the applications folder.  Thank you. I edited my original answer.

Comment: this is _almost_ what I want - I need the piece of code to be executed **immediately**, because by just telling the app to activate does open it, but doesn't run the code - the code runs after you click the jumping app icon

Comment: @Prokop Hanzl  in the script editor you have the code you want to be launched immediately, save that file as an application in script editor (XYZ.app)  then in your new script editor document, that is where you put the code:

    tell application "XYZ"
        activate
    end tell